# php query with multiple loop templates

Tags: php, loops, grid, output

I am trying to create a template for my bones theme wordpress site that has the following grid.

[GRID VISUAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t1ln.jpg)

I can't seem to figure out how to call ALL my posts from the database and output them using a number of loops with different templates that I've set up with the bones CSS

Example Query:

```
<?php $args = array(
        'post_type' => array ( 'post' ),
        'post_count' => 4
        );

        $query = new WP_query ( $args );
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    $count = 0;
        }
?>

<section class="blog-posts grid">

<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    if ( get_post_type() == 'post' && $count == 0 ) {

      include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of2.php' ));

        $count++;           

    }

    endwhile; ?>

</section>
```

and then upping the count on the second run. All that's happening is it's displaying the same post (of 12).

Thanks for the help in advance

EDIT:

With the code from mtr.web

I now have this

```
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

  if ( get_post_type() == 'post') {
      switch($count) {
          case 0:
              include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of1.php' ));
              break;
          case 1:
              include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of2.php' ));
              break;
          case 2:
              include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of2.php' ));
              break;
                    case 3:
              include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of3.php' ));
              break;
          case 4:
              include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of3.php' ));
              break;
          case 5:
              include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of3.php' ));
              break;   
          default:
              include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of1.php' ));
      }
      $count++;           
  }

endwhile; ?>
```

Which is awesome and nails the brief but I need to now effectively run this loop for ALL my posts, so duplicating this 6 post strucure again and again and again - is there a way to tell the loop to run those template locators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where your template files are or what *exactly* you are looking to do, but hopefully this can point you in the right direction.  Using a [switch/case comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php), you could change the output and/or templates being used based on the counter that you are already implementing:

**EDIT:**
By resetting the counter to 0 every time it hits a multiple of 6, you can repeat the same pattern for all posts:

```
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

  if ( get_post_type() == 'post') {
      $count++;
      switch($count) {
          case 1:
              include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of1.php' ));
              break;
          case 2:
              include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of2.php' ));
              break;
          case 3:
              include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of2.php' ));
              break;
          case 4:
              include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of3.php' ));
              break;
          case 5:
              include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of3.php' ));
              break;
          case 6:
              include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of3.php' ));
              count = 0;
              break;   
          default:
              include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of1.php' ));
      }           
  }

endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: OMG YOU ARE THE WONDER OF LIFE !

Comment: @TimHughes - I'm happy to help.  If this worked for you, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: I'm trying to add more question to this, basically I've made your code work for me which is awesome but I have a set of 6 cases, is there a way to now duplicate this format for the rest of the posts, say I have 10 posts, I want the same format to happen again until I run out of posts